# JQuery UI Datepicker not firing on click (no errors)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I am trying to get a datepicker showing up when clicking on a form field, but the datepicker dialog doesn't show up. 
Interestingly, the jquery includes the datepicker div but then simply doesn't show up or get filled with any content.

The javascript error console doesn't show any errors, as far as I can see.

The head section (shortened) :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/theme/sporthub/scripts/jqueryui/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://d2oqbtqshlvsrd.cloudfront.net/jquery.corner.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/theme/sporthub/scripts/jqueryui/jquery-ui-1.8.16.min.js"></script>
```

The form field :

```
<div class="field1"><input id="donation_start" type="text" name="donation_start" value="<?= $a_donationsSetting['donation_start'] ?>" class="date_123 marginL14 hasDatepicker" /></div>
```

The datepicker call :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $( "#donation_start" ).datepicker();
});
```

When I open the site and look at it using Firebug, I can see the following line showing (It is not in the actual source code so I guess it gets included by datepicker..??)

```
<div class="ui-datepicker ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all" id="ui-datepicker-div"></div>
```

I have tried to call the datepicker by using $('.hasDatepicker').datepicker instead, and also by not putting it within the document.read(). No success.

What puzzles me most is that the datepicker is used in another included file as well, and it works perfectly fine.

Comment: a) Why are you including jQuery UI twice? b) are you getting any errors? and 3) have you tried no including jquery.corner.js?

Comment: Is your link to the CSS file correct? If you click on the datepicker, and you scroll to the bottom of the page, do you see the datepicker there? In Firebug you should be able to detect where the datepicker HTML is.

Comment: @j08691 a) I am honestly not sure. It is a big CMS that I have not built, so I don't know why some of the things are the way they are. b) As I said, I am not getting any errors. c) No. I don't know what happens if I take it out, due to a)
@ Niels Yes the link is correct. I could not see the datepicker, just the <div> I posted in my question.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

My coworker just showed up and told me to remove the hasDatepicker class. 
That fixed the issue.

Apparently, jquery-ui adds this class in the process, and when it is already there, the datepicker won't fire.

Comment: Worked for me. This is one of those things where you end up copying elements from somewhere else where it works and it turns out the class on it is auto generated.

Comment: Wow, what an incredibly unintuitive fix! I swear I looked at that class at least 5 times thinking, "I don't remember naming that, but I want it to have a datepicker so I guess it stays" Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, z-index was the culprit. It uses a z-index relative to the input, so be sure your input field has CSS position:relative set, in my case I had to adjust the z-index to 10 for it to work;